# Is there a way in which one can read data stored in a file with extension of .sql?

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way in which one can read data stored in a file with extension of .sql in an app

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that what you want to do is copy the SQL file as the default sqlite DB?

As explained [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html#_sql).

```
if(Preferences.get("firstTime", true)) {
    Preferences.set("firstTime", false);
    String p = Display.getInstance().getDatabasePath("myDb.SQL");
    Util.copy(Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/localDb.sql"), FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(p));
}
// now use the DB as usual
```